# Confine messages by id to threads in Camel

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

In my application I consume messages from a queue, process them, write the results to a database and send to another queue. Since there are lots of IO, I want to process the messages in parallel to improve the performance.

But there's a limitation imposed by the app's architecture: to prevent data races, messages pertaining to the same entity (say "customer") cannot be processed concurrently.

The most intuitive solution would be to use the [Sticky Load Balancer](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/eips/sticky-eip.html):

```
from("jms:queue:in")
    .loadBalance().sticky(header("customerId"))
        .to("seda:x")
        .to("seda:y")
        .to("seda:z")
    .end();
```

But this approach has 2 downsides:

- I cannot change the amount of processing threads by just changing a config property
- For each seda-endpoint here I'll have to copy-paste the exact same route (or at least I don't know how to avoid the copy-paste)

Could you please show me a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

The [camel-jms](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html) component has `asyncConsumer`, `concurrentConsumers`, `maxConcurrentConsumers` options you can use to control whether messages get consumed asynchronously and how many async consumers you wish to use. This would probably remove the need to use seda all-together.

```java
from("amqp:queue:{{example.queue.name}}" 
    + "?asyncConsumer={{example.queue.consumer.async}}"
    + "&concurrentConsumers={{example.queue.consumer.count}}")
    // ...
```

As for the Sticky Load Balancer, it won't really help you to prevent "data races" or concurrency problems as it's job is just to balance the load between two or more endpoints.

For that you might have to use some sort of batching and synchronous process that processes the batch in away that doesn't cause these race conditions.

Then there could be ways to use Java Synchronization to handle this.

Also tried to look if camels aggregate could handle this reliably by using header customerId as `correlationExpression` but seems that its still possible for aggregate to fire twice if the processing takes long.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a solution using java synchronization, but wanted to know if Camel can rid me of this low-level code which is pretty hard to understand. And aggregation won't help indeed, because there's no predefined time frame and no expected amount of messages for a given correlation id. So, I'm sorry, but unfortunately I cannot accept your answer.